# What's the condition to prove the equicontinuity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, constructive-mathematics

Let $K: I\times I\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be a scalar kernel, where $I=[0,1]$, and $a: I \rightarrow  (0,+\infty)$ an $L^1(I)$ function.

For $t_1,t_2\in I$, define
$$I_{t_1,t_2}=\int_{0}^{1}  \left |\big(K(t_2,s)-K(t_1,s) \right | \cdot a(s) \, d s 
                + \int_{t_1}^{t_2}  \left |K(t_2,s)\right | \cdot a(s)  \, d s$$

Can you suggest (optimal, if possible) conditions on $K$ and $a$ so that the following holds?

> For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for any $t_1,t_2\in I$, if $| t_1-t_2|<\delta$ then $I_{t_1,t_2}<\epsilon.$

Comment: Where is $\delta$ in the desired conclusion?

Comment: And where is the Banach space $E$?

Comment: I made the necessary modifications. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I guess this will be true if $K$ is continuous.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I dont think that the continuity of $K$ will be enough, since the $\delta$  depends on $\epsilon $ only + we can not apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem here.

Comment: Perhaps one of the first (natural) requirements that comes to the mind is that $K$ to be bounded and satisfy a Hölder regularity condition, e.g., (1) $|K(t,s)|\leq M_1$ for all $s,t\in I$ (2) $|K(t_1,s)-K(t_2,s)|\leq M_2|t_1-t_2|^{\alpha}$ for all $s,t_1,t_2\in I$ for absolute constants $\alpha, M_1, M_2>0$.

Comment: @Onur Oktay good idea, Thank you.

Comment: Are you quite sure that $\delta$ is not allowed to depend on $K$?

Comment: There is one operator $K$.

Answer (score 4):

Continuity of $K$ suffices.

*Proof.* Assume that $K$ is continuous and let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Since $I\times I$ is compact we know that $K$ is uniformly continuous. By uniform continuity of $K$ we may find a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $t_1,t_2,s\in I$ we have that $|K(t_2,s) - K(t_1,s)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2\|a\|_{L_1}}$ if $|t_2-t_1| < \delta$. Now, it follows from dominated convergence that $(t_1,t_2)\mapsto \int_{t_1}^{t_2}a(s)ds$ is a continuous function. By using the compactness of the diagonal of $I\times I$, we may further assume that $\delta$ is small enough so that if $|t_2-t_1| < \delta$ then $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}a(s)ds < \frac{\varepsilon}{2\|K\|_{\infty}}$. Now, if $|t_2-t_1| < \delta$ we get:
$$
I_{t_1,t_2} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2\|a\|_{L_1}} \|a\|_{L_1} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2\|K\|_{\infty}}\|K\|_{\infty} = \varepsilon.
$$

**Improved condition**

Assume that $K$ is bounded and continuous in the first variable (i.e. $K(\cdot,s)$ is continuous for each $s\in I$). Then the conclusion holds.

*Proof.* Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given and let $C$ be a constant such that $|K| \leq C$. Using the same argument as above we may find $\delta > 0$ such that if $|t_1-t_2| < \delta$ then $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}a(s)ds < \varepsilon / (2C)$. Further, the function $(t_1,t_2)\mapsto \int_0^1|K(t_2,s)-K(t_1,s)|a(s)ds$ is continuous by dominated convergence. By using the compactness of the diagonal of $I\times I$ we see that we may further assume that $\delta$ is small enough so that if $|t_1-t_2| < \delta$ then $\int_0^1|K(t_2,s)-K(t_1,s)|a(s)ds < \varepsilon / 2$. Now it follows that if $|t_1-t_2| < \delta$ then $I_{t_1,t_2} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, the continuity of $K(.,.)$ is a very strong condition.

Comment: Using a similar idea, I think one can show that it suffices for $K$ to be bounded and continuous in $t$.

Comment: I dont think so, there is an integral, that is $s$ is not fixed...

Comment: Do you see any mistake in the proof?

Comment: $\delta$ in the second part depend on $s$, No?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry for taking your time, I don't see why: Let's say that we want to prove that: $\int_{0}^{1}\left | K(t_2,s)- K(t_1,s)\right |ds\rightarrow 0 $ when $\left | t_2-t_1 \right |\rightarrow 0$, but we don't have to fixe neither $t_1$ nor $t_2$, first. I don't think that we can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem, for one reason: we can't fix $t$ at first. If you can give a detailed answer to this part, I will be very very grateful

Comment: We are assuming that $K$ is continuous in the first variable and bounded by a constant $C$. 
Claim: The function $F:(t_1,t_2)\mapsto \int_0^1|K(t_2,s)-K(t_1,s)|a(s)ds$ is continuous. 
Proof. Let $(t_{1,n},t_{2,n})\rightarrow (t_1,t_2)$. Consider the sequence $(s\mapsto |K(t_{2,n},s)-K(t_{1,n},s)|a(s))_n$. Each function in the sequence is dominated by $2C a(s) \in L_1$ and the sequence converges pointwise to $|K(t_2,s)-K(t_1,s)|a(s)$ so the claim follows by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Now, the function $F$ is zero on the diagonal of $I\times I$ so you can find a neighborhood $U$ of the diagonal such that if $(t_1,t_2)\in U$ then $F(t_1,t_2) < \varepsilon.$ By compactness of the diagonal, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|t_1-t_2| < \delta$ then $(t_1,t_2)\in U$. Thus, if $|t_1-t_2|< \delta$, then $F(t_1,t_2) < \varepsilon$. Is this now clear?

Comment: Sorry, why we have this "By compactness of the diagonal, there exists a "$\delta>0$" such that if $\left | t_1−t_2 \right | <\delta$ then $(t_1,t_2)\in U$"?

Comment: Because the diagonal is compact, you can find $\delta' > 0$ such that if $(t_1,t_2)$ is within $\delta'$ distance from the diagonal then it is in $U$. Now, just note that if $|t_1-t_2| < \delta$ then $(t_1,t_2)$ is at distance $\delta/2$ from the diagonal (measured in the max-norm).